# treat string as object name in a loop in R

Tags: r, string, loops, object

I want to create a string in a loop and use this string as object in this loop. Here is a simplified example:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  x <- paste("varname",i, sep="")
  x <- value
}
```

the loop should create varname1, varname2. Then I want to use varname1, varname2 as objects to assign values. I tried paste(), print() etc.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't use `assign()` to create many vars. Instead learn how to work with lists and functionals https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/535931179556691968

Comment: Whenever you have the urge to create sequentially named variables, you should be using a list instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061

Comment: A fairly common question from new users is: How do I assign names to a group of similar objects?" Yes, you can do that, but you probably don't want to better is to: vectorize your thinking. Put all of the similar objects into one list. Subsequent analysis and manipulation is then going to be much smoother. [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) page 20.

Comment: @Metrics Too bad that there is no example of such manipulation in the book

Answer (score 11):

You could create the `call()` to `<-` and then evaluate it.  Here's an example,

```
value <- 1:5

for (i in 1:2) {
    x <- paste("varname",i, sep="")
    eval(call("<-", as.name(x), value))
}
```

which creates the two objects `varname1` and `varname2`

```
varname1
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
varname2
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But you should really try to avoid assigning to the global environment from with in a method/function.  We could use a list along with `substitute()` and then we have the new variables together in the same place.

```
f <- function(aa, bb) {
    eval(substitute(a <- b, list(a = as.name(aa), b = bb)))
}

Map(f, paste0("varname", 1:2), list(1:3, 3:6))
# $varname1
# [1] 1 2 3
#
# $varname2
# [1] 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all for your helpful answers! The solution with call() works very well. I'll try the more R-ish strategies as soon as I understand what's really going on (I am spoiled by Stata and thinking in loops).

Comment: Ok, I upvoted your solution. I played with it...and now I want to upvote your solution for 1k times more. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
assign("variableName", 5)
```

would do that.

For example if you have variable names in array of strings you can set them in loop as:

```
assign(varname[1], 2 + 2)
```

More and more information

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assign.html

Comment: So If I've got this right, it assigns to variable name 1, the value of 4 (evalulating 2+2 without needing to be told to do so).

Answer (score 1):

@MahmutAliÖZKURAN has answered your question about how to do this using a loop. A more "R-ish" way to accomplish this might be:

```
mapply(assign, <vector of variable names>, <vector of values>,
       MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Or, as in the case you specified above:

```
mapply(assign, paste0("varname", 1:2), <vector of values>,
       MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: A more R-ish way to do things is to use lists and not `assign`.

Comment: Yes, all the answers do what the OP asked for. I'm just picking on yours for the "more R-ish" quip ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for some reason my apply's weren't working (lapply, assign directly, or my preferred goto, mclapply)

But this worked

```
vectorXTS <- mclapply(symbolstring,function(x)
    {
      df <- symbol_data_set[symbol_data_set$Symbol==x,]
      return(xts(as.data.frame(df[,-1:-2]),order.by=as.POSIXct(df$Date)))
    })

    names(symbolstring) <- symbolstring
    names(vectorXTS) <- symbolstring

    for(i in symbolstring) assign(symbolstring[i],vectorXTS[i])
```